# How to read child nodes using Spring cloud zookeeper configuration

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

I am not able to read child nodes of an application by using Spring Cloud Zookeeper configuration.

For simplicity, lets assume, i have named it as Myapplication, and the same name node i have created in Zookeeper under config (/config/Myapplication). I have created one property inside the node such as (/config/Myapplication/sample 1).
So "sample" property i am able to access my application.

But Suppose if i have one child node under Myapplication (/config/Myapplication/Configuration config). Now, i need to access "config" property under the Configuration node thats not happening.

I tried accessing by below code in my application, But no luck :-

```
@Value("${Configuration/config: Default Child Node config}")
    private String config;
```

Please Suggest some way to move forward from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in short, if you define node like this:

```
/config/<Your-App-Name>/consumerId 12345
```

you should to be able to access it like:

```java
@Value(${consumerId})
private String consumeId
```

Note.- you can only define your variables as following:

```
/config/<Your-App-Name>/yourVar1 val1
/config/<Your-App-Name>/yourVar2 val2 ...etc
```

nodes defined as child of /config/ can be accessed easily by springboot.

more technical details [here](https://medium.com/@senthil_c/distributed-configuration-using-zookeeper-client-with-curator-in-spring-boot-7431bdd8e996)

Answer (score 1):

@Value("${Configuration.config: Default Child Node config}")
    private String config;